# SQL Grouping by Month on dates fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I need the sum of the employees Money made but grouped into the months between two dates, however I have a date field and want the name of the months and year as two separate fields.

This query is showing the un-grouped information - minus the year and month in the formats required.

Once I have the Employees money made for that month I need it sorted by Name (already done) and by Month year within each employee

```
SELECT   Employee.Name      
, Employee.ID       
, Sales.Date         
, Sales.Money            
FROM Database.Sales.Sales       
INNER JOIN Database.Employee.Employee        
ON Sales.ID=Employee.ID        
WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01'            
ORDER BY Employee.Name
```

Thanks

Comment: I should add I need the NAME of the month not as an interger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query:

```
SELECT   Employee.Name      
, Employee.ID       
, Sum(Sales.Money)
, Year(Sales.Date)           
, Month(Sales.Date)
FROM Database.Sales.Sales       
INNER JOIN Database.Employee.Employee        
ON Sales.ID=Employee.ID        
WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01'            
group by 
    Employee.Name      
    , Employee.ID
    , Year(Sales.Date)           
    , Month(Sales.Date)
ORDER BY Employee.Name,  Year(Sales.Date), Month(Sales.Date)
```

Comment: The raw Sales.Date would be lost due to the grouping on year and month

Comment: Also, as noted in anothe persons post, you'll get better performance aliasing the  Date conversion functions results in the select fields then grouping on those alias vs. calling the date functions twice for each field.  (or three times as in the case of your order by)

Comment: if performance measure of the algorithm is not square of n, it would not harm. 2n or 3n is linear, square of n is exponential.

Comment: Got this working - Instead of having the months as integers how would you get it to display the name of the month?

Comment: You can use this function: DateName(month, Sales.Date). But you should add this field to both select and group by clauses.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Month()` and `Year` functions you can use and group by.  Incorperate something like this into your query:

```
SELECT Employee.Name, 
       Employee.ID, 
       MONTH(Sales.Date) as `month`, 
       YEAR(Sales.Date) as    `year`,
       SUM(Sales.Money)       
 FROM Database.Sales.Sales        
   INNER JOIN Database.Employee.Employee ON Sales.ID=Employee.ID        
 WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01'  
   GROUP by Employee.Name , Employee.ID, `month` , `year`        
 ORDER BY Employee.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT   Employee.Name      
, Employee.ID       
, Datepart(year,sales.Date),Datepart(month,sales.Date)        
, sum(Sales.Money)
FROM Database.Sales.Sales       
INNER JOIN Database.Employee.Employee        
ON Sales.ID=Employee.ID        
WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01' 
Group by Datepart(year,sales.Date),Datepart(month,sales.Date),Employee.Name,Employee.id           
ORDER BY Employee.Name
```

Comment: You'll get better performance aliasing the Date functions results in the select list then grouping on those vs. calling the date functions twice for each field

Answer (score 0):

Date split in 2 Felds

```
SELECT   Employee.Name      
    , Employee.ID       
    , YEAR(Sales.Date) as sales_year
    , MONTH(Sales.Date) as sales_month
    , Sales.Money            
    FROM Database.Sales.Sales       
    INNER JOIN Database.Employee.Employee        
    ON Sales.ID=Employee.ID        
    WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01'            
    ORDER BY Employee.Name
```